# How to get an enumeration of types in an object array by a single key in typescript

Tags: typescript

```
let arr= [{ key: 1, age:22 }, { key: 2, age: 33 }, { key: 4, age: 44}]
```

and get type `1 | 2 | 4`

result:

```
type ArrKey = 1 | 2 | 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's check the type of the `arr` with `typeof` operator:

```
let arr = [
  { key: 1, age: 22 },
  { key: 2, age: 33 },
  { key: 4, age: 44 },
]

// type ArrKey = {
//   key: number;
//   age: number;
// }[]
type Arr = typeof arr;
```

The compiler widens the types to primitives to make it easier to manipulate, which is not what we want here. To prevent widening we can use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
let arr = [
  { key: 1, age: 22 },
  { key: 2, age: 33 },
  { key: 4, age: 44 },
] as const;


// type ArrKey = readonly [{
//   readonly key: 1;
//   readonly age: 22;
// }, {
//   readonly key: 2;
//   readonly age: 33;
// }, {
//   readonly key: 4;
//   readonly age: 44;
// }]
type ArrKey = typeof arr
```

Now, to get the values for `key` we will use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get a union of the array's elements:

```
// type ArrKey = {
//   readonly key: 1;
//   readonly age: 22;
// } | {
//   readonly key: 2;
//   readonly age: 33;
// } | {
//   readonly key: 4;
//   readonly age: 44;
// }
type ArrKey = typeof arr[number]
```

Now by using indexed access again let's get the `key` property:

```
// type ArrKey = 1 | 2 | 4
type ArrKey = typeof arr[number]['key']
```

Looks good!

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjEF4IG0BQEIG8IGsQE8AuCARgBpoBzEYgJlogF8z0tcC6KpriBmXpiwzY8RCABYuPCeMGoAutADOEAMYB7AHZKwAblQGA9IYhh8ABxAQAgnADSBRKQgAfCAzfjUZyzfuOkHxB1ADNoOGRNAFcAWwAjEBh5ZAByURT5IA)